# PDE-Poisson Equation $u_{xx}+u_{yy}=-1$??

Tags: partial-differential-equations, poissons-equation

I want to solve the partial differential equation $$u_{xx}+u_{yy}=-1$$ in the region $0<x<1, y>0$ subject to the boundary conditions $u(0,y)=0, u(1,y)=1$ and $u(x,0)=0$.

Comment: Avoid no-clue question: [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959).